# If $U\to X$ is a closed immersion, $U$ is dense in $X$ and $X$ is reduced, why is the closed immersion an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

This came up in the Reduced-to-separated theorem.

If $U\to X$ is a closed immersion, $U$ is dense in $X$ and $X$ is reduced, why is the closed immersion an isomorphism?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Could you clarify?

Comment: I think the question is clear: it's asking the difference between set-theoretic equality and scheme-theoretic equality. Basically, if $U\to X$ is a closed immersion and the image is dense in $X$ and $X$ is reduced, why is it an isomorphism?

Comment: Take a field $k$, and consider the closed immersion $\mathrm{Spec}\,(k) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,(k[T]/(T^2))$. It is topologically the embedding of a point into a point, but the structural sheaf isn't quite the same.

Comment: A closed dense subscheme $i:U\hookrightarrow X$ is given by a homeomorphism $U\to X$ that induces a surjective morphism $\mathcal{O}_X\to i_*\mathcal{O}_U$. In other words, we want an ideal sheaf $\mathscr{I}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_X$ whose support is empty. If we look at this on affine patches $U=\mbox{Spec}(B)$ and $X=\mbox{Spec}(A)$, this means we're looking for an ideal $I\subseteq A$ that's contained in the nil radical of $A$, but since the nil radical is $0$ ($A$ is reduced), we obtain that $I=\{0\}$.

Comment: I was writing this as an answer when the question was closed!

Comment: I don't see how Pece's example should contest that I implied in my question. Spec $(k[T]/(T^2))$ is not reduced. @FredrikMeyer, my question is exactly as Robert Auffarth reformulated it. I don't see what else could be still clarified.

Comment: @Rodrigo My example was answering the question stated in the title : "Why do we need $X$ to be reduced … ?", well because otherwise it does not hold as a counter example (like the one given) shows. The question stated in the corpus by Robert Auffarth is quite different. Consider modifying the title.

Comment: @Pece, you're correct. My appologies.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Well, as it was originally formulated, the question body was practically empty, and the only question was in the title - without motivation and context (and it was not particularly clear what was being asked). However, now as the question has changed, I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Being an isomorphism is local on the target and closed immersions are finite (in particular affine). Thus it suffices to show the affine case.

A closed immersion between affine schemes corresponds to the quotient map of a ring modulo an ideal. If the topological spaces are the same, the ideal has to be contained in the nilradical of the ring (intersection of all prime ideals). Since the ring is reduced, the nirlarical is zero and the quotient map is an isomorphism. Therefore the corresponding affine scheme morphism is an isomorphism, as we wanted to show.